# Unable to Add DSC Extension JSON ARM

Tags: azure, powershell, dsc, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to add an extension to an azure arm template, so when it loops around it adds the extension to each vm.

The full JSON is at the link below:
https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/7uvwdZ6e

The error I'm getting is:

```
Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template validation failed: 'The resource 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/vmt1dsc/extensions/CreateADPDC' at line 
'0' and column '0' is defined multiple times in a template.
```

CreateADPDC' is the name of the extension.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your dsc extension (line 444, I believe) is this (and because of that it complains it is defined multipli times):

```
"name": "[concat(parameters('VMNames'),'/',parameters('vmNameDscConfig'))]",
```

but should be this:

```
"name": "[parameters('vmNameDscConfig')]",
```

small remark, you need full name\type for "sub" resource (think subnet, vm extension, nsg rule, etc) if you are declaring it as a stand alone resource, but yours is a nested resource of the VM resource, so `type` should be `extensions`, just like with other extensions, not:

```
"type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
```